# Issue with rendering the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

As here you can see my showData is null initially, and I have given a if condition but I dont know why it is making it True.

Comment: You have given condition  as OR which is wrong , it should be AND condition inside if. As its OR condition its getting bypassed by first condition i.e. (null!=="undefined") which is TRUE. So change || to && , it will work fine.

Comment: give more details, like what is happening...and what you want as your output behavior

Comment: @Tejas thanks. It was such a silly mistake.

Comment: you can write this way like ```if(showData)```

Comment: @VikasSingh u can see the debug console on left side.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer :

```
showData !== undefined && showData !== null && showData !== ""
```

Easier answer:

```
if(showData )
{
  //truthy, wont include any of the above conditions
}
```

Easiest answer:

```
{showData  &&
  //render stuff
}
```

Long answer:
This is expected behavior. You are asking it if `showData` is undefined OR null OR empty string, which is true. You want to make sure none of these are true and thus you should be asking if `showData` undefined AND NOT null AND NOT empty string

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer. It was a silliest question. I will definitely use this rather than giving such long logical consitions

Comment: Might be useful for someone in the future to have it explained. @AyushiKeshri